# DWORD to bytes using bitwise shift operators

Tags: c++

I can't get it to work correctly.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD i  = 6521;

    BYTE first = i >> 32;
    BYTE second = i >> 24;
    BYTE third = i >> 16;
    BYTE fourth = i >> 8;

    i = (((DWORD)fourth) << 24) | (((DWORD)third) << 16) | (((DWORD)second) << 8) | first;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the fact that you are shifting eight bits too many, you are also reconstructing `i` in reverse order (this may be intended).

Comment: Better use uint32_t and uint8_t for integral types of fixed size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
BYTE first = (i >> 24) & 0xff;
BYTE second = (i >> 16) & 0xff;
BYTE third = (i >> 8) & 0xff;
BYTE fourth = i & 0xff ;
```

Comment: Bah, my answer will run faster.  One less op.  Even better on an ARM proc with shift optimization :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Yours is more confusing, and appears to be the same number of operations.  So not faster.

Answer (score 2):

I think You shift Your DWORD too much. By 8 bits too much :)

Answer (score 2):

Your shifts are not quite correct.

```
BYTE first  = i         >> 24;
BYTE second = i <<  8   >> 24;
BYTE third  = i <<  16  >> 24;
BYTE fourth = i <<  24  >> 24;
```

What I am doing is shifting down 24 for the top byte, then shifting up in increments of 8 to clear the top bits and place the next byte in position for the shift down.

You could read the value at dword as a byte array (or struct) of 4 bytes to do this as well and let the compile do the work for you.

Comment: Bit-shifting on `BYTE forth` needs a fix, If you would.

Answer (score 1):

The bytes aren't always in the order that you expect, though Neil's solution is correct. You probably want to look at "[endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)" if you're having that problem